# auf/für die Prüfung lernen

Tags: preposition

Can either of the two prepositions be used in this expression without any difference?

> „Kommst du mit ins Kino?“ - „Nein, ich muss noch **auf**/**für** die Prüfung lernen.“

Answer (score 7):

No, they can not be used without any difference. »Auf« is wrong. To pass the exam is your goal, and learning is the way how you want to reach this goal. So you do the learning *for* something, not *on* something.

Correct is:

> Ich muss noch **für** die Prüfung lernen.

Comment: »Auf« cannot be wrong. Quotations: 1) »[Er hat von früh bis spät <...> auf die Prüfung gelernt.](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/fr%c3%bch)« 2)  »[Ich habe zu viel auf die Prüfung gelernt, ich kann gar nichts mehr aufnehmen.](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/aufnehmen)« 3) »[Er hat Tag und Nacht auf die Prüfung gelernt. Obwohl er sich so gut vorbereitet hat, ist er durchgefallen.](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Vorfeld.html)«

Comment: @stillenat possibly another North-South thing? I'll ask my (Northerner) colleagues next week if I remember. It sounds wrong-ish to me, too, though; but I can't pinpoint why.

Comment: Berlin here.. it's odd to me but not unheard of. I definitely wouldn't call it wrong. Also, using English translations of prepositions in reasoning that is based on logic and common sense makes no sense. You also wait "for" a bus and not "on" it and yet it's "warten auf", go figure. -1 since the answer needs a substantial do over.

Comment: some more hits: https://www.google.de/search?q=%22auf+die+Pr%C3%BCfung+zu+lernen%22&hl=de&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=rg5EVfmDJI_LaN6ZgPAP&ved=0CAQQ_AU

Comment: 'auf' is colloquial. In standard German it is wrong, imo.

Comment: @TaW... auf der ersten Trefferseite für die Phrase "auf die Prüfung zu lernen" sind allerdings einige Beispiele dabei, die ich nicht als "colloquial" einstufen würde. Ausserdem... wer definiert denn, welche Präposition im Standarddeutsch "korrekt" ist?

Comment: Kann ich nichts finden, oder sind Amzon Bewertungen jetzt ein Maßstab? Dazu spanische Fahrschulen und wörtliche Rede und so weiter. Naja, im Zweifelsfall mein Sprachgefühl ;-) Und das ist hier __sehr__ deutlich!

Comment: @TaW Hier sind einige Bücher für dich: [google.de/...](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22auf+die+Pr%C3%BCfung+zu+lernen%22&btnG=Nach+B%C3%BCchern+suchen&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=de&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: Ja. __Schlechtes Deusch ist weit verbreitet__ und wird auch jederzeit abgedruckt.. Wenn es im Duden ankommt und daduch sanktioniert wird, kann ich auch nichts mehr ausrichten. Der war aber (noch) nicht dabei, oder..? (Kann aber ja noch kommen; es ist ja die Regel: __Wenn genug Leute einen Fehler machen ist es keiner mehr.__ Es gab mal die Regel: _Wer 'brauchen' ohne 'zu' gebraucht, der braucht es gar nicht zu gebrauchen._ Passé..)

Comment: @TaW: Warum ist Deutsch, das nicht den Regeln entspricht, sofort automatisch *schlechtes* Deutsch, oder gar fehlerhaft? Deutsch ist eine lebende Sprache, das heißt, sie verändert sich ständig. Nach deiner Logik ist alles, was zu irgend einer Zeit in der Vergangenheit den damaligen Regeln widersprochen hat, schlecht und fehlerhaft, und das einzig gute und korrekte Deutsch wäre demnach vermutlich jenes, das von Walther von der Vogelweide verwendet hat.

Comment: @TaW Welch ein schöner Kommasetzungsfehler im fettgeschriebenen Teil deines Kommentars ;)

Comment: He, du meinst der Umbruch gilt nicht?? Aber ja, Meines Sprachgefühls bin ich mir sicher; meiner Kommata überhaupt nicht.. ;-)

Comment: @TaW: Vor allem stößt mir der Satz »Wenn genug Leute einen Fehler machen ist es keiner mehr« sauer auf. Eine gewachsene Abweichung wird von irgend einer Organisation als Regel anerkannt, wenn diese Abweichung weit genug verbreitet ist. Diese Abweichung war aber nie ein Fehler, sonder nur eine Variation. Der tatsächliche Gebrauch einer Sprache ist das eigentliche Regelwerk. Das man üblicherweise als Regeln bezeichnet, sind nur daraus abgeleitete Zusammenhänge. Wenn es hier eine Diskrepanz gibt, ist nicht die verwendete Sprache schlecht, sondern die Regel ist ungenau oder falsch.

Comment: @hubert: 1. Es gibt schlechtes Deutsch. Wenn du anderer Meinung bist: Tut mir leid für dich.. 2. Der Einzelfall ist eben das. 3. Wenn du meinen Kommentar richtig gelesen hättest, wüsstest du, dass mir der Sprachwandel durchaus bekannt ist. 4. Diese Website hat das Ziel aktuelle Standarddeutsch zu vermitteln. qed.

Comment: _Diese Abweichung war aber nie ein Fehler, sonder nur eine Variation._ Na toll; es gibt also keine Fehler?? Doch! Der Satz ist übrigens die Maxime der Dudenredaktion und nein diese ist nicht 'irgendeine Organisation'. Und nein, ich bin kein Fan des BI, wohl aber ein Gegner schludriger Sprache und schludrigen Denkens.

Comment: Es sind dieser Beitrag hier und überwiegend nicht deutsche Wörterbucheinträge und Forenbeiträge die bei der Suchanfrage "auf die Prüfung lernen" bei Google ganz oben stehen. Ein Ergebnis lautet "In der eintägigen intensiven Vorbereitung auf die Prüfung lernen die Teilnehmenden den Prüfungsaufbau kennen, [...]" - hier ist die Vorbereitung auf die Prüfung gemeint. Alle anderen Ergebnisse sind umgangssprachlich oder unwissenschaftlich. Die Anfrage "für die Prüfung lernen" ergibt deutlich mehr Treffer, unter anderem Tipps von Bildungseinrichtungen. Imho: "Für die Prüfung lernen" ist richtig.

Comment: Correct or wrong - however "auf die Prüfung lernen" absolutely usual in spoken and written German.

Answer (score 2):

I did my own research and came to the conclusion that both ***für die Prüfung lernen*** and ***auf die Prüfung lernen*** are correct. From what I could infer, there doesn't seem to be any noticeable difference in meaning. The difference seems to be regional.

Two dictionary references and not-to-be-overlooked examples from German books should indicate the legitimate use of "auf". I'll include here some links that were provided in the comments to other answers:

> Er hat von früh bis spät **auf die Prüfung gelernt**. [thefreedictionary.com](https://de.thefreedictionary.com/fr%C3%BCh)
>   Ich habe zu viel **auf die Prüfung gelernt**, ich kann gar nichts mehr aufnehmen. [thefreedictionary.com](https://de.thefreedictionary.com/aufnehmen)
>   Er hat Tag und Nacht **auf die Prüfung gelernt**. Obwohl er sich so gut vorbereitet hat, ist er durchgefallen. [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Vorfeld.html)

Some Google Books search results can be found [here](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22auf%20die%20Pr%C3%BCfung%20zu%20lernen%22&btnG=Nach%20B%C3%BCchern%20suchen&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=de&gws_rd=ssl).

I read in the comments that it could be a regional thing. So I did some research on local German periodicals. I looked for the phrase "auf die Prüfung lernen" and some of its variations on Google News to see if regional news can give a clue where this expression is more commonly used. Here are my results:

German newspapers:

> Bei den Studenten kommt die Aktion gut an. Wirtschaftsstudent Markus Maier nutzt sie, um **auf eine Prüfung zu lernen**. [Reutlinger General-Anzeiger. Tübingen.](https://www.gea.de/neckar-alb/kreis-tuebingen_artikel,-aufschieberitis-und-schlaf-bek%C3%A4mpft-_arid,2461007.html)
>   Auf die Frage, wie viel sie schon **auf die Prüfung gelernt** habe, schaut sie sich verstohlen um... [Augsburger Allgemeine. Donauwörth.](https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/donauwoerth/Vor-dem-Pass-steht-der-Test-id23621796.html)
>   Doch bevor es soweit war, musste er fleißig **auf die Prüfung lernen**. [Baden Online. Schiltach.](https://www.bo.de/lokales/kinzigtal/nun-gibt-er-tipps-und-hilfestellung)
>   Ich habe ziemlich viel **auf die Prüfung gelernt**. [Fudder Neuigkeiten aus Freiburg. Littenweiler.](http://fudder.de/hauptschulpruefung-2010-wie-war-englisch)

Swiss newspapers:

> Die Kinder haben zum Teil intensiv **auf die Prüfung gelernt**. [Der Bund.](https://www.derbund.ch/front/exklusiv/Grosser-Widerstand-gegen-die-Abschaffung-der-Gymipruefungen/story/17510799)
>   Sie sind nicht die Einzigen, die **auf die Prüfung lernen**. [Neue Zürcher Zeitung.](https://www.nzz.ch/wissenschaft/bildung/eingebildete-kranke-beim-staatsexamen-1.18131228)
>   Den Ausdruck benutzten wir während des Studiums, wenn wir nicht **auf eine Prüfung gelernt** hatten. [Neue Zürcher Zeitung.](https://www.nzz.ch/die_letzten_ihrer_art-1.9386421)
>   So habe sie zu wenig **auf eine Prüfung gelernt**. [20 Minuten. Zürich.](https://www.20min.ch/schweiz/zuerich/story/Mit-Amoklauf-gedroht---18-Monate-Gefaengnis-26990701)

It's not proper linguistic research, of course. But this usage seems to be typical of south-west(?) Germany and Switzerland.

Comment: Adding on to what has been said in other comments: The more I thought about it, the more likely I feel to have used it (Bavaria). On the other hand, my colleagues from Lower Saxony, North-West of Berlin and rural Westfalia all deemed it *definitely wrong and unusual*. So it's likely North-South with usage of *auf* restricted to the South (where *für* is not considered wrong, however!)

Answer (score 0):

Besser wäre :

Ich muss noch für die Prüfung lernen.

Comment: Instead of "besser wäre", you should say "richtig ist".

Comment: @Em1... no he/she shouldn't. https://www.google.de/search?q=%22auf+die+Pr%C3%BCfung+zu+lernen%22&hl=de&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=rg5EVfmDJI_LaN6ZgPAP&ved=0CAQQ_AU

Comment: Google is simply bringing up a lot of colloquialisms. You really shouldn't believe everything you find there or in ad texts! One of them can explain the mix-up btw: One common synonym is 'sich auf die Prüfung vorbereiten'.

Answer (score 0):

For me both versions are correct, but they have a slightly difference.

> Ich muss noch für die Prüfung lernen.

I have to learn and my goal is the exam. The Knowledge itself seems not to be important. The thinking is: *We learn for school, not for life.*

This could be the answer for the question: *Why do you learn?*

> Ich muss noch auf die Prüfung lernen.

I have to learn and it must be finished before the exam starts. The thinking is: *We learn for life, not for school* — the exam is only the test for the Knowledge.

This could be the answer for the question: *Why do you learn now?*

But in a normal conversation, you would not recognize the difference.

Disclaimer: I’m a native speaker from South-West Germany.

Comment: I see only one difference: One ('lernen auf') is wrong/colloquial and one is correct standard German ('lernen für'). No difference in meaning. The contrived difference is nonsense: 'lernen für die Prüfiung' is already opposed to 'lernern fürs Leben'